# Convergence of Dirichlet kernel

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a monotonic and bounded function defined on [0,1) and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)$ exists. Prove
\begin{align}
\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1 f(x)\frac{\sin\lambda x}{x}dx =  \frac{\pi}{2}f(0^+)
\end{align}

I am thinking of dividing this integral into two parts:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)\frac{\sin\lambda x}{x}dx = \int_0^\delta+\int_\delta^1 f(x)\frac{\sin\lambda x}{x}dx
\end{align}

It is easy to show the second part goes to zero, however I don't really know how to deal with the first part. In other words, I need to estimate
\begin{align}
\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^\delta (f(x)-f(0^+))\frac{\sin\lambda x}{x}dx = 0
\end{align}
However $\frac{\sin\lambda x}{x}$ is oscillating and is not absolutely integrable.

Comment: Why do you say it is not absolutely integrable? It seems to be well-behaved near 0?

Comment: @timur I mean $\int_0^\infty |\frac{\sin x}{x}| dx= \infty$.

Comment: @MarkViola: Yes, but $\delta$ is small (depending on $\lambda$).

Comment: Try breaking up at $\delta = {k \over \lambda}$, and showing that your estimates go to zero as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I think one needs to use monotonicity somehow, because without that one needs Dini continuity (if I remember correctly).

Comment: @timur I tried using mean value theorem for integral, which requires the monotonicity of f. But it seems that it does not work...

Comment: @Zarrax Do you mean $k$ is something like $\sqrt{\lambda}$?

Comment: That should work too.

Comment: But if that still gives you trouble, fix $k$ and then show that for large enough $\lambda$, your integral differs from the desired limit by a function of $k$ which goes to zero as $k$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @Zarrax I typed out the answer. Is this what you mean?

Comment: For the first integral yes. For the second part you need to effectively integrate by parts or an analogous thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Inasmuch as $f(x)$ is monotonic and bounded on $[0,1)$, it is almost everywhere continuous there and therefore integrable.

---

Note that we can write the kernel $\frac{\sin(\lambda x)}{x}$ as the integral

$$\frac{\sin(\lambda x)}{x}=\frac12\int_{-\lambda }^\lambda e^{i x t}\,dt\tag 1$$

Using $(1)$ we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)\frac{\sin(\lambda x)}{x}\,dx&=\frac12\int_0^1 f(x)\int_{-\lambda }^\lambda e^{i x t}\,dt\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\lambda }^\lambda \int_0^1 f(x)e^{i x t}\,dx\,dt\\\\
&=\frac12\int_{-\lambda }^\lambda \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\xi_{[0,1]}(x)e^{i x t}\,dx\,dt\\\\
\end{align}$$

Letting $\lambda \to\infty$ yields

$$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\int_0^1 f(x)\frac{\sin(\lambda x)}{x}\,dx=\frac12\int_{-\infty }^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\xi_{[0,1]}(x)e^{i x t}\,dx\,dt\tag2$$

Since $f(x)\xi_{[0,1]}(x)\in L^1$, the inner integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ is the Fourier Transform of $f(x)\xi_{[0,1]}(x)$.  And the outer integral is $2\pi$ times the inverse Fourier Transform of the Fourier Transform, evaluated at $0$.

Inasmuch as $f(x)\xi_{[0,1]}(x)$ is discontinuous at $0$, we conclude [See this on the Fourier Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem#Integrable_functions_in_one_dimension) that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\int_0^1 f(x)\frac{\sin(\lambda x)}{x}\,dx&=\pi \left(\frac12 (f(0^+)\xi_{[0,1]}(0^+)+\frac12f(0^-)\xi_{[0,1]}(0^-)\right)\\\\
&=\frac\pi2 f(0^+)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: I just found that 1/2 is missing. Is this because we have $f\xi_{[0,1]}$ is discontinuous at the point 0 so we have the last limit $\frac{f\xi_{[0,1]}(0^+)+f\xi_{[0,1]}(0^-)}{2} \pi = \frac{\pi f(0)}{2}$ instead?

Comment: Because $f(x)$ can be discontinuous, there's no guarantee that your limit as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$ even exists. Even if it did, $f(x)\xi_{[0,1]}(x)$ doesn't necessarily have a jump discontinuity at $x = 0$ and therefore the division by 2 at the end is not justified.

Comment: @Cris Yes, you are correct.  I've edited accordingly.  Good catch!

Comment: @MarkViola The version of the Fourier inversion theorem you quoted requires that $f(x)$ is piecewise smooth. Keep in mind $f(x)$ is only assumed to be monotonic and bounded here. You were objecting to my integration by parts before; you're now adding a similar assumption.

Comment: @zarax And where did I "object to [your] integration by parts?"

Comment: I asked you "Does $ \int_0^1 \cos(\lambda x) d\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)$ exist?"  The issue is at $0$.  Do you see?

Comment: Ok I'll replace it with the mathematical content: Monotonic functions can have infinitely many discontinuities. Not to mention, continuous isn't the same as smooth. From your wiki article: "
f can only have countably many discontinuities in its domain. The discontinuities, however, do not necessarily consist of isolated points and may even be dense in an interval $(a,b)$."

Comment: For the above reasons, I am convinced your argument does not work, and cannot easily be corrected. I will now exercise my right to not discuss the matter any further.